# Parse Email Verification inverse

Tags: parse-platform

There is a method in Parse to send the confirmation e-mail with a link to not confirm? Because in the app is uncomfortable to go out and confirm and return.

Something like "If you decided to signup here, please ignore this link, otherwise if you not, click on the link"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Parse SDK, you aren't forced to use the email verification. It's just an option. So your user are able to register without the need of email verification and they will get the pass recovery mail if they don't have verified address.

Comment: Yes but in this way, an user can signup with an email of another person. My request is the email with a "no confirmation link", also with external services